# Remove boilerplate from db code

Tags: java, jdbc

It seems that every time I want to perform a db query, I have to write the following:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;

try {
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    // ...set stmt params
    rset = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rset.next()) {
        // Do something interesting
    }
} finally {
    try { if (rset != null) rset.close(); } catch(SQLException e) { }
    try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException e) { }
    try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch(SQLException e) { }
}
```

Is this really the best way to do this? Is there a way to at least reduce some of the clutter?

Edited: as some of the comments pointed out, this code wasn't long *enough*.

Comment: By the way, you should check each for being null before closing.

Comment: @Robert - not that it's nice and I agree a null check should be added, but the NullPointerException will be caught in the catches block (along with OutOfMemoryError and all the other rumtime exceptions that could happen).

Comment: If you're going to do the JDBC code yourself it worth writing a JDBCUtils class that has safeClose methods for each JDBC class.  These methods should check for null and catch/log SQLException.

Comment: Don't just log exceptions, but let caller know that error occured, otherwise caller cannot react to a problem (and in some cases it may want to). Spring JDBC Template solves this nicely by converting exceptions to runtime exceptions hierarchy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have a DataSource you can use [Spring JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch13s02.html) for:

- greatly reduced boilerplate code
- have a good [sql exception hierarchy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch12s02.html) to handle common database problems with specific runtime exceptions
- (later with further Spring usage) use declarative transaction management

If it seems too heavy for the moment you could implement some utility classes and methods for the 'boilerplate part'. Studying the source of JdbcTemplate should help in this case.

Comment: Spring's SQL Exception hierarchy rocks. Jdbc support in Spring is something I try to use if possible, or at least copy, if spring is not in the project.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, use the Sping JDBC Template classes (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html).

Or if you don't use Spring copy the template pattern that they are using in your own code.

Answer (score 6):

[DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) is a very useful framework, I've used it for smaller projects where Spring and Hibernate are overkill. It's able to do some object mapping as well.

Comment: +1 Nice catch - I like it! It looks like they've essentially packaged up the "helper" approach I've described. I'll have to keep it in mind for next time. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Make a helper method?

```
public class DBHelper
{
    public static Object run(string sql, List params, ResultHandler rhandler)
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            int i = 0;
            for(Object p in params)
            {
                stmt.setObject(++i, p);
            }
            rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            return rhandler.handle(rset);
        } finally {
                try { rset.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
                try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
                try { conn.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        }
    }
}

public interface ResultHandler
{
    public Object handle(ResultSet)
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = (String)DBHelper.run("select * from mytable where col = ?",
                Arrays.asList({"foo"}), 
                new ResultHandler
                {
                    public Object handle(ResultSet r)
                    {
                        r.first();
                        return r.getString("col2");
                    }
                }();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/) or [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/overview/faq/persistence.jsp) to reduce the clutter...