# Anything wrong with using a DB wrapper Class like this?

Tags: java, mysql

Is there anything wrong with using a parent function to handle all the messy catch/finally stuff in a connection pool?

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        return this.dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public ResultSet executeQuery(Connection connection, PreparedStatement stmt) {
    try {
        return stmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Avoid all that boiler plate code, use Spring JDBC Templates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1072994/791406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of the [*Facade Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

There's nothing wrong with it, except your should make those methods `static`, so they are (stateless) utility methods.

Answer (score 3):

No problem except the fact that you are eating the exceptions and not throwing them.Throwing an exception is a better idea to allow the calling methods to take appropriate actions.

**Note**: if you can move to Java 7 and use try with resource then you will save a lot of such mess. Learn more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Can you show me an example?  I am pretty sure I am on java 7 and this must be a new feature.

Comment: @MasterGberry check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have much cleaner code if you use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern and focus on minimizing the scope of your resources.  In particular, you problematically open resources (the connection and the statement) separately from the close behavior.  By splitting it up, you make it easy to make mistakes, or create inefficient code.  For example, perhaps you should not close the connection after executing the query.

Instead, you should generally open and close resources in the same place, and anywhere you pass around these resources you trust (create an invariant) that they are and will remain open.  This cleanly compartmentalizes the obtaining-resources behavior from the using-resources behavior, and lets you clearly limit the scope these resources are open for.

Compare your code:

```
Connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = ...; // construct PreparedStatement
ResultSet rs = executeQuery(conn, ps);
// use ResultSet

/* now secretly your Connection and PreparedStatement are closed (even if you wanted
   to use them again) though your result set is still open and needs to be closed.

   Admittedly it's concise, but what's actually going on is very unclear. */
```

To my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection()) {
        // All calls in this block, and only calls in this block, can use the connection
        buildObjectWithDBData(conn); // method does exactly what the name implies
        // do more calls against our connection as needed
    }
}

public static void buildObjectWithDBData(Connection conn) {
    try(PreparedStatement ps = /* generate prepared statement */;
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        // do work with result set, populate the data we need
    }
    // at this point we know the connection is alive in a clean, stable state,
    // the resources opened here are closed, and we've done the work we need
}
```

I'll grant, mine is a little more verbose.  But it's *much* more clear what it's doing, and at every step in the process we explicitly limit the scope of our objects and resources to as little as possible, rather than relying on side-effects of arbitrary method calls to secretly close objects and leave them still in scope, but unusable.